# ASP.net 5 Web API Post CreatedAtRoute always returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

The database works. It does actually insert the new record, but when I use CreatedAtRoute(), I always get a 500 back from the client. Why?

My controller's Get:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class IngredientController : Controller
{
    private SimpleCookbookDbContext db { get; set; }

    public IngredientController(SimpleCookbookDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Ingredient>> Get()
    {
        return await db.Ingredients.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetIngredient")]
    public async Task<Ingredient> Get(int id)
    {
        return await db.Ingredients.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Ingredient ingredient)
    {
        try
        {

            var res = await IM.CreateAsync(ingredient);

            if (!res.Success)
            {
                return HttpBadRequest(res.Errors);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }


        return CreatedAtRoute("GetIngredient", new { controller="Ingredient", id = ingredient.Id });
    }
}
```

I tried debugging this. Yes, it would return the HttpBadRequest if the ingredient I'm trying to insert already exists.

I tried putting a breakpoint inside the catch block, and I'm not getting there, so I assume there was no error from the database.

The record does get inserted to the database. I do get to the line `return CreatedAtRoute(...);` but I get a 500 back. (I set a breakpoint there, too).

Now, I'm using fiddler. My request is this:

```
POST /api/ingredient HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:55303
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

{"id":0, "name": "rosemary", "description": "rosemary"}
```

I also removed the double quotes on the property names, and I still get the same 500.

I do have camel-casing resolved at the Startup:

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
```

I think I showed all relevant code. If you need more, please let me know.

---

**UPDATE**

CreatedAtRoute has an overload taking in three parameters:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetIngredient", new { controller="Ingredient", id = ingredient.Id }, ingredient);
```

The last parameter is an object, which you could create dynamically or pass back your entire entity, depending on what you want to expose back.

It's strange how there's a 2-parameter variant that would result in a strange 500 response.

Comment: In these kind of scenarios you can use the `DeveloperExceptionPage` middleware to see the exception details. As the name suggests this middleware should be used in Development environment.